# How do I Overlay/Merge images in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a background image and a foreground image. And I want to display one, on top of the other. The foreground image may not cover the entire area of the background image.

So, I make calls to thse functions in the given order

```
 PaintSliced(b2.rect, new Rect(p._BackImageUV.X, p._BackImageUV.Y, p._BackImageUV.Width, p._BackImageUV.Height), p._BackImage, p, p._Slice);

PaintSliced(b2.rect, new Rect(p._ForeImageUV.X, p._ForeImageUV.Y, p._ForeImageUV.Width, p._ForeImageUV.Height), p._ForeImage, p, p._Slice);
```

However, the foreground image (of equal width and height, but lower area) is covering the entire background image. Its basically, over-writing the entire rectangle.

How do I achieve the functionality I need. I hope I was clear with the question.

```
        private void PaintSliced(Grid gr,Rect UVRectangle, String imgpath, UIControl_Prop props, UISlice sliced)
        {
            //gr.Background = null;
            if (sliced.Equals(UISlice.yes) && props._BackImage != null && props._BackImage != "")
            {
                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                src.BeginInit();
                src.UriSource = new Uri(imgpath, UriKind.Absolute);
                src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                src.EndInit();
                //9 slice parameters have yet to be passed
                //TODO implement a new property for 9 slicing parameters
                //Default params are 20% of the actual size of the control
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imgpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(fileStream, BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
                    //Size s = new Size(frame.PixelWidth, frame.PixelHeight);
                    Size s = UVRectangle.Size;

                    Rectangle   dTopLeft, dTopCenter, dTopRight,   //Destination Rectangles
                                dMidLeft, dMidCenter, dMidRight,
                                dBottomLeft, dBottomCenter, dBottomRight;

                    Rect sTopLeft, sTopCenter, sTopRight,   //Source Rectangles
                              sMidLeft, sMidCenter, sMidRight,
                              sBottomLeft, sBottomCenter, sBottomRight;

                    int side_control; //side used by the control
                    int side = side_control = (int)(s.Width < s.Height ? s.Width*0.2f : s.Height*0.2f);

                    if (2 * side > gr.Width || 2 * side > gr.Height)
                        side_control = (int)(gr.Width < gr.Height ? gr.Width / 2 : gr.Height / 2);

                    s = new Size(frame.PixelWidth, frame.PixelHeight);

                    ImageBrush ib1 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Top Left*/
                    sTopLeft = new Rect(0 + UVRectangle.X / s.Width, 0 + UVRectangle.Y / s.Height, side / s.Width, side / s.Height);
                    dTopLeft = new Rectangle();
                    dTopLeft.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dTopLeft.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dTopLeft.Width = dTopLeft.Height = side_control;
                    //dTopLeft.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, 0, gr.Width - side_control, gr.Height - side_control);
                    ib1.Viewbox = sTopLeft;
                    dTopLeft.Fill = ib1;
                    gr.Children.Add(dTopLeft);

                    ImageBrush ib2 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Top Center */
                    sTopCenter = new Rect((UVRectangle.X+ side) / s.Width,  0 + UVRectangle.Y / s.Height, (UVRectangle.Width - 2 * side) / s.Width, side / s.Height);
                    dTopCenter= new Rectangle();
                    dTopCenter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dTopCenter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dTopCenter.Height = side_control;
                    dTopCenter.Width = gr.Width - 2 * side_control;
                    dTopCenter.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(side_control, 0, 0, 0);
                    ib2.Viewbox = sTopCenter;
                    dTopCenter.Fill = ib2;
                    gr.Children.Add(dTopCenter);

                    ImageBrush ib3 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Top Right*/
                    sTopRight = new Rect((UVRectangle.X + UVRectangle.Width - side) / s.Width, 0 + UVRectangle.Y / s.Height, side/s.Width, side/s.Height);
                    dTopRight= new Rectangle();
                    dTopRight.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dTopRight.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dTopRight.Height = side_control;
                    dTopRight.Width = side_control;
                    dTopRight.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(gr.Width - side_control, 0, 0, 0);
                    ib3.Viewbox = sTopRight;
                    dTopRight.Fill = ib3;
                    gr.Children.Add(dTopRight);

                    ImageBrush ib4 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Middle Left*/
                    sMidLeft = new Rect(UVRectangle.X/s.Width, (UVRectangle.Y + side)/s.Height, side/ s.Width, (UVRectangle.Height - 2*side) / s.Height);
                    dMidLeft = new Rectangle();
                    dMidLeft.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dMidLeft.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dMidLeft.Height = gr.Height - 2 * side_control;
                    dMidLeft.Width = side_control;
                    dMidLeft.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, side_control, 0, 0);
                    ib4.Viewbox = sMidLeft;
                    dMidLeft.Fill = ib4;
                    gr.Children.Add(dMidLeft);

                    ImageBrush ib5 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Middle Center*/
                    sMidCenter = new Rect((UVRectangle.X + side)/s.Width, (UVRectangle.Y + side)/s.Height, (UVRectangle.Width - 2 * side) / s.Width, (UVRectangle.Height- 2 * side) / s.Height);
                    dMidCenter = new Rectangle();
                    dMidCenter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dMidCenter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dMidCenter.Height = gr.Height - 2 * side_control;
                    dMidCenter.Width = gr.Width- 2 * side_control;
                    dMidCenter.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(side_control, side_control, 0, 0);
                    ib5.Viewbox = sMidCenter;
                    dMidCenter.Fill = ib5;
                    gr.Children.Add(dMidCenter);

                    ImageBrush ib6 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Middle Right*/
                    sMidRight= new Rect((UVRectangle.X + UVRectangle.Width - side)/s.Width,(UVRectangle.Y +side)/s.Height, (side)/s.Width, (UVRectangle.Height - 2 * side) / s.Height);
                    dMidRight = new Rectangle();
                    dMidRight.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dMidRight.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dMidRight.Height = gr.Height - 2 * side_control;
                    dMidRight.Width = side_control;
                    dMidRight.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(gr.Width - side_control, side_control, 0, 0);
                    ib6.Viewbox = sMidRight;
                    dMidRight.Fill = ib6;
                    gr.Children.Add(dMidRight);

                    ImageBrush ib7 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Bottom Left*/
                    sBottomLeft= new Rect(UVRectangle.X/s.Width, (UVRectangle.Y + UVRectangle.Height- side)/s.Height, side/s.Width, side/s.Height);
                    dBottomLeft = new Rectangle();
                    dBottomLeft.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dBottomLeft.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dBottomLeft.Height = side_control;
                    dBottomLeft.Width = side_control;
                    dBottomLeft.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, gr.Height - side_control, 0, 0);
                    ib7.Viewbox = sBottomLeft;
                    dBottomLeft.Fill = ib7;
                    gr.Children.Add(dBottomLeft);

                    ImageBrush ib8 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Bottom Center*/
                    sBottomCenter = new Rect((UVRectangle.X + side) / s.Width, (UVRectangle.Y + UVRectangle.Height - side) / s.Height, (UVRectangle.Width - 2 * side) / s.Width, side / s.Height);
                    dBottomCenter = new Rectangle();
                    dBottomCenter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dBottomCenter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dBottomCenter.Height = side_control;
                    dBottomCenter.Width = gr.Width - 2 * side_control;
                    dBottomCenter.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(side_control, gr.Height - side_control, 0, 0);
                    ib8.Viewbox = sBottomCenter;
                    dBottomCenter.Fill = ib8;
                    gr.Children.Add(dBottomCenter);

                    ImageBrush ib9 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Bottom Right*/
                    sBottomRight = new Rect((UVRectangle.X + UVRectangle.Width - side) / s.Width, (UVRectangle.Y + UVRectangle.Height - side) / s.Height, side / s.Width, side / s.Height);
                    dBottomRight = new Rectangle();
                    dBottomRight.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dBottomRight.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dBottomRight.Height = side_control;
                    dBottomRight.Width = side_control;
                    dBottomRight.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(gr.Width - side_control, gr.Height - side_control, 0, 0);
                    ib9.Viewbox = sBottomRight;
                    dBottomRight.Fill = ib9;
                    gr.Children.Add(dBottomRight);
                }
            }
            else if(props._BackImage != null && props._BackImage != "")
            {

                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                src.BeginInit();
                src.UriSource = new Uri(imgpath, UriKind.Absolute);
                src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                src.EndInit();
                ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(src);
                ib.Viewbox = new Rect(UVRectangle.X / src.PixelWidth, UVRectangle.Y / src.PixelHeight, UVRectangle.Width / src.PixelWidth, UVRectangle.Height / src.PixelHeight);
                gr.Background = ib;
            }
```

Comment: Why not simply do a PNG with transparency? You're seemingly reinventing the wheel with all this. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: What screenshot are you looking for? I need to just overlap two images. What's the easier way?

Comment: What was your initial reason for using this code, I am wondering?  Are you trying to do 9 slice image scaling?

Comment: @Kik - Yes. I did not understand the code myself until now. Please read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863245/how-to-overlay-two-images-in-wpf-using-9-slice

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you just want some images with transparency on top of each other. It is very unclear to me why you're doing all that behemoth amount of (ugly) code.

Try this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"  Width="800" Height="600">

    <Grid>
        <Image Source="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/SRU-Logo-Transparent.png"/>

        <Image Source="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Triple-Spiral-4turns_green_transparent.png"/>

        <Image Source="http://www.axdn.com/redist/axpssp_logo.png"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

- Replace the `Source` property of the `Image` elements as needed (with paths to images on your local drive, or better with [paths to `Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) within your WPF application).
- Make sure you use `PNG` or other image format that supports transparency (JPG will not work here).
- Set the [`Panel.ZIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex(v=vs.110).aspx) attached property as needed to define the Z-Order of UI elements within a Panel (such as a `Grid`).
- **Get used to doing UI-related things with XAML rather than procedural code in WPF.**

Comment: I don't know why so much code has been written. I have not written them. Where in your code are you enabling or disabling transparency?

Comment: @Paul the PNG file format has built-in support for transparency, so does WPF. There's no "enabling / disabling" of anything.

Comment: It appears to me that the function he is using is doing 9 slice image scaling, so just loading the image normally and displaying it will not work.

Comment: @Kik See my comment below the question where I asked for clarification and the OP stated that he needed to *"just overlap two images"*.

Comment: @Kik- I could not understand the code at all and thus, asked only for the overlap two images part.
But, basically, the code breaks the images into 9 rectangles and then sets the Rectangle.Fill attribute. Now, in my understanding, that fills the entire rectangle thereby covering the image behind. 

For ex- If I have a circle over a square, I want the circle over the square. I don't need the circle to be transparent. I just want the parts not covered by the circle to be visible