# How to overlay two images in WPF using 9 slice?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am going to present some (dirty) code, which I don't understand completely because I am new to C#.

From my understanding, any control which is to be drawn is broken up into 9 rectangles and then each rectangle is drawn separately by setting the `Fill` attribute of a Rect

I shall hide the code for each of the rectangles to keep the code of manageable size, but, I hope you get what the function is trying to achieve.

Now, the problem, that I need to solve is that I need to print two images, one on top of the other.

For, example, I need a solid circle on top of a solid rectangle. So, I can see the entire circle but only the corners of the rectangle. I do not want the circle to be transparent. The original circle.png does NOT have a rectangular border. Its border is along the boundaries of the circle only. Thus, ideally, the entire circle should not overlap the rectangle.

But, if I call the function given below twice, once for the rectangle and then for the circle, the entire rectangle is overlapped. I don't want that. What should I do?

```
        private void PaintSliced(Grid gr,Rect UVRectangle, String imgpath, UIControl_Prop props, UISlice sliced)
        {

            //gr.Background = null;
            if (sliced.Equals(UISlice.yes) && props._BackImage != null && props._BackImage != "")
            {
                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                src.BeginInit();
                src.UriSource = new Uri(imgpath, UriKind.Absolute);
                src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                src.EndInit();
                //9 slice parameters have yet to be passed
                //TODO implement a new property for 9 slicing parameters
                //Default params are 20% of the actual size of the control

                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imgpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(fileStream, BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
                    //Size s = new Size(frame.PixelWidth, frame.PixelHeight);
                    Size s = UVRectangle.Size;

                    Rectangle   dTopLeft, dTopCenter, dTopRight,   //Destination Rectangles
                                dMidLeft, dMidCenter, dMidRight,
                                dBottomLeft, dBottomCenter, dBottomRight;

                    Rect sTopLeft, sTopCenter, sTopRight,   //Source Rectangles
                              sMidLeft, sMidCenter, sMidRight,
                              sBottomLeft, sBottomCenter, sBottomRight;

                    int side_control; //side used by the control

                    int side = side_control = (int)(s.Width < s.Height ? s.Width*0.2f : s.Height*0.2f);

                    if (2 * side > gr.Width || 2 * side > gr.Height)
                        side_control = (int)(gr.Width < gr.Height ? gr.Width / 2 : gr.Height / 2);

                    s = new Size(frame.PixelWidth, frame.PixelHeight);

                    ImageBrush ib1 = new ImageBrush(src);


                    /*Top Left*/
                    sTopLeft = new Rect(0 + UVRectangle.X / s.Width, 0 + UVRectangle.Y / s.Height, side / s.Width, side / s.Height);
                    dTopLeft = new Rectangle();
                    dTopLeft.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dTopLeft.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dTopLeft.Width = dTopLeft.Height = side_control;
                    //dTopLeft.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, 0, gr.Width - side_control, gr.Height - side_control);
                    ib1.Viewbox = sTopLeft;
                    dTopLeft.Fill = ib1;
                    gr.Children.Add(dTopLeft);

                    ImageBrush ib2 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Top Center */
                    sTopCenter = new Rect((UVRectangle.X+ side) / s.Width,  0 + UVRectangle.Y / s.Height, (UVRectangle.Width - 2 * side) / s.Width, side / s.Height);
                    dTopCenter= new Rectangle();
                    dTopCenter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dTopCenter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dTopCenter.Height = side_control;
                    dTopCenter.Width = gr.Width - 2 * side_control;
                    dTopCenter.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(side_control, 0, 0, 0);
                    ib2.Viewbox = sTopCenter;
                    dTopCenter.Fill = ib2;
                    gr.Children.Add(dTopCenter);

                    ImageBrush ib3 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Top Right*/
                    sTopRight = new Rect((UVRectangle.X + UVRectangle.Width - side) / s.Width, 0 + UVRectangle.Y / s.Height, side/s.Width, side/s.Height);
                    dTopRight= new Rectangle();
                    dTopRight.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dTopRight.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dTopRight.Height = side_control;
                    dTopRight.Width = side_control;
                    dTopRight.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(gr.Width - side_control, 0, 0, 0);
                    ib3.Viewbox = sTopRight;
                    dTopRight.Fill = ib3;
                    gr.Children.Add(dTopRight);

                    ImageBrush ib4 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Middle Left*/
                    sMidLeft = new Rect(UVRectangle.X/s.Width, (UVRectangle.Y + side)/s.Height, side/ s.Width, (UVRectangle.Height - 2*side) / s.Height);
                    dMidLeft = new Rectangle();
                    dMidLeft.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dMidLeft.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dMidLeft.Height = gr.Height - 2 * side_control;
                    dMidLeft.Width = side_control;
                    dMidLeft.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, side_control, 0, 0);
                    ib4.Viewbox = sMidLeft;
                    dMidLeft.Fill = ib4;
                    gr.Children.Add(dMidLeft);

                    ImageBrush ib5 = new ImageBrush(src);
                    /*Middle Center*/
                    sMidCenter = new Rect((UVRectangle.X + side)/s.Width, (UVRectangle.Y + side)/s.Height, (UVRectangle.Width - 2 * side) / s.Width, (UVRectangle.Height- 2 * side) / s.Height);
                    dMidCenter = new Rectangle();
                    dMidCenter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    dMidCenter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    dMidCenter.Height = gr.Height - 2 * side_control;
                    dMidCenter.Width = gr.Width- 2 * side_control;
                    dMidCenter.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(side_control, side_control, 0, 0);
                    ib5.Viewbox = sMidCenter;
                    dMidCenter.Fill = ib5;
                    gr.Children.Add(dMidCenter);
                }
            }
            else if(props._BackImage != null && props._BackImage != "")
            {

                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                src.BeginInit();
                src.UriSource = new Uri(imgpath, UriKind.Absolute);
                src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                src.EndInit();
                ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(src);
                ib.Viewbox = new Rect(UVRectangle.X / src.PixelWidth, UVRectangle.Y / src.PixelHeight, UVRectangle.Width / src.PixelWidth, UVRectangle.Height / src.PixelHeight);
                gr.Background = ib;
            }

            if (props._TextHandle != -1)
                PaintText(gr, props._Text, props);
        }
```